# Facing issues harvesting data from a table

Tags: python, css, xpath, web-scraping

Writing a script in python to get data from table, when I use xpath I get the data according to it's row and column wise format. However, when I use css selector with the same I get an error 'list' object has no attribute 'text'. How to get around that? Thanks in advance?

Using xpath which is working errorlessly:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url="https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/"
response = requests.get(url).text
tree = html.fromstring(response)
for titles in tree.xpath("//table[@class='ism-table']")[0]:
    for row in titles.xpath('.//tr'):
        tab_d = row.xpath('.//td/text()')
        print(tab_d)
```

Using css selector with the same I get aforesaid error:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url="https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/"
response = requests.get(url).text
tree = html.fromstring(response)
for titles in tree.cssselect("table.ism-table")[0]:
    for row in titles.cssselect('tr'):
        tab_d = row.cssselect('td')
        print(tab_d.text)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it. This is how it works:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

response = requests.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/").text
tree = html.fromstring(response)
for titles in tree.cssselect("table.ism-table")[0]:
    for row in titles.cssselect('tr'):
        tab_d = [item.text for item in row.cssselect('td')]
        print(tab_d)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tab_d` is a `list` but you want it to be an `element` or `node` or something like that.

try:

```
tab_d = row.cssselect('td')
[print(x.text) for x in tab_d]
```

Comment: Thanks sir jmunsch for your answer. I'm not around my pc at this moment. As soon as I'm I'll give you the feedback.

Comment: i don't use dropbox, sorry. @SMth80

Comment: Just see above. Thanks.